# Sitesync Sitefinity backend pages

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I added a Sitefinity backend page through the Administration -> Backend Pages tool... however, this does not show up anywhere in the Sitesync I can find, and there's no apparent way of migrating this in the Backend Pages control itself.

How do you sync new backend pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to sync backend pages. You can find a detailed list of synchronized and not synchronized content here: https://docs.sitefinity.com/synchronized-content

**Backend Pages** is in the list "Not synchronized data", you **cannot** sync it.

You need to recreate it manually on your destination server

Comment: Thanks for the info. That answered my question in my mind